# How to update Ruby with Homebrew?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I want to know how to update to the latest **stable** version of Ruby with Homebrew. I am **not** interested in using RVM. Thanks.

Comment: Are you against RVM or version managers in general? If you don't have old rubies installed, you won't be able to run older Ruby libraries on your computer. Rbenv can be frendlier. I'm not even sure the latest Ruby versions are pushed to system package managers like Homebrew. On ubuntu, the default Ruby version is still 1.9.3

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`brew upgrade ruby`

Should pull latest version of the package and install it.

`brew update` updates brew itself, not packages *(formulas they call it)*

Answer (score 222):

I would use [`ruby-build`](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#usage) with `rbenv`. The following lines install Ruby 3.3.0 and set it as your default Ruby version:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew install rbenv

$ rbenv install 3.3.0
$ rbenv global 3.3.0
```

Comment: Is there no way to automatically update to the latest, stable version of Ruby without "hard coding" the version in there? Something like `rbenv install latest`?

Comment: I prefer to have more control over the version, but you might want to use this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30191850/2483313

Comment: Thanx for the answer.
I had to run this as well:
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Thank you! I then had to run `gem install rails` to get rails and it was all working

Comment: The rbenv install felt like it was stuck so if you want to make sure some progress is being made run:  

`$ rbenv install --verbose 2.4.0`

Comment: Ok, that worked well, but then how do you update your system to use the homebrew version rather than the default one?

Comment: @chrismarx did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, see this thread, but basically, you need "eval "$(rbenv init -)" in your ~/.bash_profile - https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/815

Comment: if you have a .ruby-version file in your project directory or from wherever you are calling the ruby command, you still need to update that with `rbenv local 2.6.1` otherwise it will override the global setting

Comment: you do not need this `brew install ruby-build` as it is installed as a dependency when you are installing rbenv.

Comment: Also you have to add this: `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to your .bash_profile or .zshrc, whatever you are using, so that you point to the above version of ruby and not the system one.

Comment: you can check the `latest` version available by using `rbenv install -l`

Answer (score 15):

To upgrade Ruby with rbenv:  Per the [rbenv README](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#upgrading-with-homebrew)

- Update first: `brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build`
- See list of Ruby versions: versions available: `rbenv install -l`
- Install: `rbenv install <selected version>`

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the selected answer (as I haven't enough rep to add comment), one way to see the list of available versions ([from ref](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions)) try:

```
$ rbenv install -l
```

Answer (score 3):

I followed [@spickermann's instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36485498/5365001), but I was still running into trouble with the Mac System Ruby install being primary (`ruby -v` did not show my newly installed `global` ruby).  I solved it by executing three more steps:

1. ```
   rbenv init
   ```
2. Following the instructions which appeared in the console.  For me, using `.zshrc`:

   ```
   # Load rbenv automatically by appending
   # the following to ~/.zshrc:
   eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
   ```

   Yours may be different if you use `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, instead of `.zshrc` - in all circumstances, you [should be able to change the `eval` statment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485180/how-to-update-ruby-with-homebrew#comment104862428_36485498/5365001) to

   ```
   eval "$(rbenv init -)"
   ```

   and have it work equivalently.
3. Start a new terminal (or re-source your `rc` file).  For me, using `.zshrc`:

   ```
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```

After following those steps, `ruby -v` showed the desired version of Ruby and not the system-installed version.

---

Answer (score -4):

open terminal

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

restart terminal then

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.2
```

check ruby version it should be  2.4.2

Comment: OP specifically asked NOT rvm.