# Reinstall default Ruby on MacOS Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos

I have been playing around with Jekyll and Ruby on my mac. I insalled Ruby 2.4 via MacPorts, messed something up and accidently deleted `/Library/Ruby`. I am now worried that I have messed up internals on my system.

How can I reinstall default Ruby Gems for Ruby 2.0 that comes with MacOS Sierra?

Comment: There may be a less destructive way to do it. But you could always reinstall OS X over your current installation. This will replace all the system files but should keep your documents and stuff in check. However you may lose other elements of your configuration.

Comment: or maybe install rvm and use one of it's ruby as default. You can get away from using system ruby and settings most of the time.
Using rvm/rbenv gives flexible advantage that if things go south, you can always nuke and reinstall.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use such an old version of Ruby? Ruby `2.0` reached end-of-life more than one and a half year ago and is unsupported. I  suggest using a Ruby version manager like `rbenv` and [installing an up-to-date version of Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36485498/2483313).

Comment: Hi, purely because that's the version that ships with Mac OS Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Install rbenv

```
brew install rbenv
```

2) Install ruby version

```
rbenv install 2.0.0
```

3) Set your global env to 2.0.0

```
rbenv global 2.0.0
```

3 bis) Or set your local env to 2.0.0

```
rbenv local 2.0.0
```