# Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run bundle install, I get no errors. But when I try to run puma, I get the error:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 95251
Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2
! Unable to load application: SystemExit: exit
```

but when I run `rbenv local`, I get: `3.1.2`

and `ruby -v` gives: `ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-linux]`

and my Gemfile has `ruby "3.1.2"`

Why does Puma still think it should be 3.0.2? I should note that I'm running puma with sudo... because I want to have the ability to run https on port 443 at 0.0.0.0 - when I run `rails server` all by itself, everything works fine and Puma shows 3.1.2 as expected.

I've looked through other similar questions and I haven't found anything that works.

Comment: aha! Running sudo ruby -v gives me 3.0.2, and sudo which ruby shows /usr/bin/ruby - that's why it expects 3.0.2. How do I upgrade the default ruby under sudo?

Comment: Why did you install Ruby with sudo in the first place. That is usually not recommended. Instead, [install `3.1.2` with rbenv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36485498/2483313) and use that version.

Comment: Always start Rails using `bundle exec rails server` to use the *bundled* version of Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the development and deployment setups I've seen, the Ruby server is not run on port 443 directly. As far as I'm aware, doing that is quite unusual. Instead, a higher port is used, which doesn't require root access. In deployment, port 443 would be served by a proxy in front of the Ruby process, like Nginx or [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/).

I'm struggling to reproduce your issue. The key difference I can see between our setups is that for you, `sudo which ruby` shows `/usr/bin/ruby` (system Ruby), whereas I get `/home/brendan/.rbenv/shims/ruby` (rbenv Ruby). This is probably due to the `$HOME/.rbenv/shims` directory not being part of the `PATH` environment variable within your `sudo` environment. Perhaps the applicable [`rbenv init` command](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation) is not running there? Check you've followed these rbenv installation instructions.

You can more readably view the entries within your sudo environment's `$PATH` with:

```bash
sudo env | grep PATH | sed s/^PATH=// | tr : '\n' | sort
```

As said in the comments, when running an executable from a gem, always prefix it with `bundle exec` to ensure you're using the version of it and its dependencies that are in your `Gemfile.lock`. And to avoid headaches when using a Ruby version manager (like rbenv), avoid using the Ruby that's installed by your system package manager.

If you feel you must use port 443 and hence `sudo`, I'm sure there's a way to get that to work; but I'd recommend side-stepping the issue entirely by using a different port number. If there is something requiring you to use 443, perhaps you should be looking for a way to address that issue instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you have installed ruby 3.1.2 (you can install using rbenv or rvm)

Then make it default

Store `3.1.2` in `.ruby-version` file under your project directory

Clean the Gemfile.lock

Bundle install

Comment: I'd reckon there must already be a `.ruby-version`. Without one, `rbenv` instead outputs `rbenv: no local version configured for this directory` rather than what was provided in the question